# Easiest way to add two points

Tags: javascript

I have two points `a` and `b`:

```
var a = new Point(10, 20);
var b = new Point(5, 15);
```

I would like to create a third point `c` that is a sum of `a` and `b` like this:

```
// same as new Point(15,35)
c = new Point( a + b )
```

To do this, I know I have to override prototypes `valueOf()` method. But it needs to return both x and y value to be able to do as the example...

Any hints on how to implement my `Point` class?

Answer (score -1):

```
function Point(x, y) {
    if(x.isObject && y.isObject){
        this.x = x.x + y.x;
        this.y = x.y + y.y;
    } else {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

You cannot work with overloads, so you need to check the parameters. Here is a working Snippet.

```js
function isObject(value) {
    return value !== null && (typeof value === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : typeof(value)) === 'object';
}

function Point(x, y) {
    if(isObject(x) && isObject(y)){
        this.x = x.x + y.x;
        this.y = x.y + y.y;
    } else {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
} 

var a = new Point(10, 20);
var b = new Point(20, 10);
var c = new Point(a, b);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```